# Transform JS object into code / module (codegen)

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, code-generation, transpiler

There are many things that do `x -> JS` and I want to do something similar where `x` is a POJO and spits out an es module.

Currently I am writing a string then saving it to a js file:

```
const mapJoin = (xs, fn) => xs.map(fn).join(', \n');

const output = `
import { Model, belongsTo, hasMany } from '@miragejs/server';

export default {
  ${mapJoin(
    nodes,
    node =>
      `${node.model}: Model${
        !node.fields.length
          ? ''
          : `.extend({
             ${mapJoin(
               node.fields,
               f =>
                 `${f.name}: ${f.isConnection ? 'hasMany' : 'belongsTo'}('${
                   f.model
                 }')`
             )}
      })`
      }`
  )}
}`;

fs.writeFileSync('__generated__models.js', output);
```

This is very cumbersome and error prone. Is there an accepted way / library that handles this?